# How can I create 1 or 2 objects per row with dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I have a row with 4 columns of data. I want to create an object A from data in columns 1-2. If the data is not present in columns 1-2, use columns 3-4 to create an object B. In rare cases, we will have data in all columns, but data in columns 2 and 4 does not match. In that case, I want to return an object A and an object B.

Is there a way to do this in dapper using multi-mapping? Or should I return an object C that is all 4 columns, and then post process the data to create the objects A and B I actually want?

```
public class A {
  public long ID {get;set;}
  public long Value {get;set;}
}
public class B {
  public long ID {get;set;}
  public long Value {get;set;}
}
```

Objects A and B are not related to each other (i.e. A does not contain a list of B). So I am uncertain how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data is partitioned by `Id`, then it should already work if you use a wrapper type to represent the two values. For example, if we use a `Tuple<,>`, then:

```
var data = conn.Query<A, B, Tuple<A, B>>(sql,(a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b), args);
```